# The LinkButton_Click event is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a dynamic link button. I want to navigate to other pages when the click event is fired . But now, when I click on the link button, the entire page is cleared off and no click event is fired.

```
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton lbView = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton();
 lbView.Text = "<br />" + "View";
 lbView.Click += new System.EventHandler(lbView_Click);

 tc.Controls.Add(lbView);
 tr.Cells.Add(tc);

 protected void lbView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Response.Redirect("contactus.aspx");
 }
```

Please help.

Comment: Remove link button and add  new link button

Comment: @Harsh :  Can you please tell me why so?

Comment: Where are you creating the linkbutton? In Page_load?? What is tc and tr??

Comment: what you doing in Page Load event?

Comment: i think you wrap your code inside (!IspostBack){...} in page load event..

Comment: @MicrosoftDN :-  I am creating the link button after creating few other dynamic controls for which the data are fetched from database as per user selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating dynamic control you can not directly create click event of that control. In your case you must follow this way. Add `javascript` to redirect `contactus.aspx` page.

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton lbView = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton();
lbView.Text = "<br />" + "View";
btn.OnClientClick = "return RedirectTo();";  // You need to add javascript event

tc.Controls.Add(lbView);
tr.Cells.Add(tc);


// javascript
<script>
  function RedirectTo()
  {
     window.location.href = 'contactus.aspx';
     return false;
  }
</script>
```

Try this. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside like this and try :-

```
if(!IsPostBack){
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton lbView = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton();
 lbView.Text = "<br />" + "View";
 lbView.Click += new System.EventHandler(lbView_Click);

 tc.Controls.Add(lbView);
 tr.Cells.Add(tc);
}

 protected void lbView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Response.Redirect("contactus.aspx");
 }
```